# Nginx location / overrides all other locations

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I'm trying to write a simple nginx config. What I need is:

1. if file exists in root serve this file
2. If url is /default/url then show /some/path2/index.html
3. Otherwise redirect to /default/url

my config is as follows

```
    server {
    listen 127.0.0.1:80;
    server_name my.domain.com;

    root /some/path/html;

    location / {
            return 302 /default/url; 
    }

    location = /default/url {
            rewrite ^/(.*)$/some/path2/index.html;
    }

    location /default/e_schema {
            proxy_pass http://other.host.com;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
    }
}
```

It redirects to **/default/url** instantly regardless of url.
I was trying to put the **location /** block on the bottom and on the top. I've tried to use **location ~ /.*** to lower priority but nothing helps. If I remove  **location /** at all everything is fine my requirements 2 and 3 is ok.

According to this answer https://serverfault.com/questions/656628/nginx-catch-all-other-locations-than-given/656634 it should work.

Answer (score 0):

You have put an "=" in the location block

```
location = /default/url {
```

Could you try removing this? I believe it may be setting the url

Comment: No, after removing = result is the same. I ve added it because I need exact match, there are files like /default/url/style.css so removing = will lead to not sirving those files.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was here

```
location = /default/url {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$/some/path2/index.html;
}
```

this makes internal redirect to **/some/path2/index.html** which is within / path so it triggers the **location /** block which redirects to /default/url and so on.

My solution was to make empty block to exclude the path from **location /**

```
location /some/path2/index.html {}
```